# Trying to know if the website I am trying to connect is live or not via HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

I am working on an application that connect to a website and grab data from it. The problem I am having is that when I try to check whether the website is live or not sometimes it show its offline in my app but when I try the same website on the browser it's working. I have tried **HttpURLConnection** to check the response time and if it's equal to **200** return **true** but mostly it doesn't
work.It shows that website isn't online.I have used thread to give some delay to the asynctask but still its not working perfect.

Here is the code.

```
package com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Splash_Activity extends Activity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

    UserSessionManager session;
    Data data;
    ProgressWheel progress;

    boolean check;
    String url = "";

    FileInputStream inputStream;
    String filename = "newMyProfileData";
    Animation animFadein;
    Animation animFadeout;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        boolean finish = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("finish", false);
        if (finish) {

            finish();
            return;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.splast_activty);


        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);

        progress = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        url = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_URL);

        animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.blink);
        animFadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.fade_out);
        animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);
        animFadeout.setAnimationListener(this);

        animFadein.setDuration(1300);
        animFadeout.setDuration(1000);
        animFadeout.setStartOffset(1200 + animFadein.getStartOffset() + 1200);


        data = new Data(getApplicationContext());

        progress.spin();

        if(animFadein!=null)
        {
            linearLayout.startAnimation(animFadein);

        }

        if (!session.checkLogin() && isOnline()) {

            final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new checkingnetwork().execute();
                }
            }, 2000);


            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getcheck();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
        else if (!session.checkLogin() && !isOnline()) {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getcheck();
                }
            }, 4000);

        } else {
            getcheck();
        }
    }


    public void getcheck() {

        if (!data.isOnline() && !session.checkLogin()) {
            MyProfile_Data data_file;
            new MyProfile_Data();

            try {
                File filew = new File(Splash_Activity.this.getCacheDir(), filename);
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(filew);

                ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
                data_file = (MyProfile_Data) input.readObject();

                Data.name_person = data_file.getName();
                Data.name_enroll = data_file.getEnrollment();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Navigation_drawer.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


        } else if (isOnline()) {

            if (check && !session.checkLogin()) {
                Data.checkwebsite = check;
                new Login_Activity_Again(Splash_Activity.this).execute();
            } else if (!session.checkLogin() && !check) {

                MyProfile_Data data_file;
                new MyProfile_Data();

                try {
                    File filew = new File(Splash_Activity.this.getCacheDir(), filename);
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(filew);

                    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
                    data_file = (MyProfile_Data) input.readObject();

                    Data.name_person = data_file.getName();
                    Data.name_enroll = data_file.getEnrollment();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot connect to the webserver.Going into offline mode",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Data.w_check = 1;

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Navigation_drawer.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            }
        } else {
            if (session.checkLogin())
                finish();

        }
    }


    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //should check null because in air plan mode it will be null
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

       // linearLayout.startAnimation(animFadein);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }


    public class checkingnetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                // FIRST METHOD I TRIED
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                check = (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);

                // SECOND METHOD I TRIED
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                check =  (200 <= responseCode && responseCode <= 399);

                System.out.print(responseCode);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
    }

}
```

The logcat is here..

```
  1-11 23:04:24.804 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: SBServiceAPI: getService class android.os.ServiceManager
01-11 23:04:24.804 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
01-11 23:04:24.804 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-18855-353874012: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
01-11 23:04:26.204 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-11 23:04:27.824 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal time:27606813
01-11 23:04:27.984 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/debug: Screen inches : 5.2007338145504045
01-11 23:04:27.994 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
01-11 23:04:28.024 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable/header.jpg
01-11 23:04:28.114 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/profile_picture.png
01-11 23:04:28.204 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
01-11 23:04:28.204 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
01-11 23:04:28.234 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/tick_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.234 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/time_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.234 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/result_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.274 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 23:04:28.294 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 23:04:28.324 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 23:04:28.334 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 23:04:28.484 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/profile_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.484 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/progress_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.484 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/notification_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.494 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/eva.png
01-11 23:04:28.494 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/password_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.504 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/feedback_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.514 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/privacy_logo.png
01-11 23:04:28.524 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{3bfd695e V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01ad app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
01-11 23:04:28.524 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{1db4b13f V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01ad app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
01-11 23:04:28.524 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{9aada0c V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01ad app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
01-11 23:04:28.644 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@12a519a2 time:27607635
01-11 23:04:28.644 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@29c55571 time:27607635
01-11 23:04:30.024 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:116)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:150)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:97)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:198)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:119)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:777)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal.Splash_Activity$checkingnetwork.doInBackground(Splash_Activity.java:223)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal.Splash_Activity$checkingnetwork.doInBackground(Splash_Activity.java:208)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-11 23:04:30.044 10320-10638/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-11 23:05:00.344 10320-10351/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/art: Debugger is no longer active
01-11 23:05:00.644 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-11 23:06:03.744 10320-10320/com.bu.innovate.bustudentportal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@12a519a2 time:27702733
```

I tried to fix it and used two methods to solve this problem but still nothing plus sometimes when the network is slow it doesn't connect either. It would be really helpful if you guys help me solve this problem.

Comment: Can you normally access the URL like in a browser?

Comment: @cricket_007 most of the time I can.

Comment: @cricket_007, he clearly stated that he can access it via browser in his question